# Python - Returning query result from server to client in Flask

Tags: python, json, rest, flask, client-server

- **What I have**

  I have a Client/Server in Flask. The client sends a query in JSON format to the server and the server creates a JSON file. There is another tool which takes this query, executes it on a db and writes the result to a results.txt file. The server periodically checks the 'results' directory for .txt files and if it finds a new file it extracts the result. For the periodic checking part I used APS.
- **What I want to do**
  Now I want to send this data (queryResult) which the server has extracted from the .txt file back to the client.

This is what I have done so far.

- **Server Code:**

> ```
> app = Flask(__name__)
> api = Api(app)
>
> # Variable to store the result file count in the Tool directory
> fileCount = 0
>
> # Variable to store the query result generated by the Tool
> queryResult = 0    
>     
> # Method to read .txt files generated by the Tool
> def readFile():
>     global fileCount
>     global queryResult
>     # Path where .txt files are created by the Tool
>     path = "<path>"
>     tempFileCount = len(fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(path), '*.txt'))
>     if (fileCount != tempFileCount):
>         fileCount = tempFileCount
>         list_of_files = glob.iglob(path + '*.txt')
>         latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
>         print("\nLast modified file: " + latest_file)
>         with open(latest_file, "r") as myfile:
>             queryResult = myfile.readlines()
>             print(queryResult) # I would like to return this queryResult to the client
>             
> scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
> scheduler.add_job(func=readFile, trigger="interval", seconds=10)
> scheduler.start()   
>
> # Shut down the scheduler when exiting the app
> atexit.register(lambda: scheduler.shutdown())   
>    
> # Method to write url parameters in JSON to a file
> def write_file(response):
>     time_stamp = str(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"))  
>     with open('data' + time_stamp + '.json', 'w') as outfile:
>         json.dump(response, outfile)
>     print("JSON File created!")
>    
>
> class GetParams(Resource):
>     def get(self):
>         response = json.loads(list(dict(request.args).keys())[0])  
>         write_file(response)  
>            
> api.add_resource(GetParams, '/data')  # Route for GetJSON()
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     app.run(port='5890', threaded=True)
> ```

- **Client Code**

> ```
> data = {
>     'query': 'SELECT * FROM table_name'
> }
>
> url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5890/data'
>
> session = requests.Session()
> retry = Retry(connect=3, backoff_factor=0.5)  
> adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
> session.mount('http://', adapter)
> session.mount('https://', adapter)
>
> resp = session.get(url, params=json.dumps(data))
> print(resp)
> ```

Can anyone please help me as to how to send this queryResult back to the Client?

EDIT: I would like the server to send the queryResult back to the client each time it encounters a new file in the Tool directory i.e., every time it finds a new file, it extracts the result (which it is doing currently) and send it back to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is called a `Web Worker Architecture`.

To pass in a real-time abstract `queryResult` from a background job to a client app you can use a combination of a Message Queue (Kafka is recommended, RabbitMQ is OK too) and a Web-Socket. When a client sends a request to the `/data` endpoint, you should return back some unique token (like UUID if your user is anonymous, or user id if it's authenticated). The same token you should add to the name of the resulting file. When your background worker finished processing the file it uses the token (from a file's name) to create a Kafka or RabbitMQ topic, like `topic_for_user_id_1337` or `topic_for_uuid_jqwfoj-123qwr`, and publishes `queryResult` as a message.

At the same time, your client should establish a web-socket connection (Flask is quite bad for web-sockets, but there are few fine libs to do that anyway, like socketio) and pass the token through it to your backend so it'll create a message queue subscriber, subscribed to a topic with the token's name so when a background job is finished, a web-backend will receive a message and pass it to the user through a web-socket.

P.S. If it sounds overly complicated, you can avoid the use of MQ and WS and put the `queryResult` into a db and create a endpoint to check if it exists in a DB. If it's not, you return something like `not ready yet` and a client retries in a few seconds, if it's ready -- you return the `queryResult` from the DB.

Comment: I did not know about the Kafka/Rabbit MQ and Web-Socket approach so I had implemented a workaround something similar to what you mentioned. Instead of a db I just wrote the queryResult to a file and the server checked whether the contents of the file were 'None' or not. If it is, it waits and retries and if not it returns it to the client. But thank you for mentioning the other approach. I will look into it.