# Long time request in Flask with React

Tags: python, flask

I am building an application in Flask API and React.

The first page of the app presents the user with an upload file form. The user selects a file (700 MB) and click uploads.

Once this is done, the backend:

- Takes the file, unzip it
- Run some ML model
- Returns a JSON containing the right data

When this is over, react gets the JSON and renders a new page.

These three steps takes more than **10 minutes** therefore I get an error 500 which I believe is due to the long time request timeout.

I would like to know if there is a way to make `timeout=None`.

I looked for some answers and they suggest to use `Celery`. However, I am not sure if this is the right approach for my task.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making an asynchronous task in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866796/making-an-asynchronous-task-in-flask)

Comment: While you could increase the timeout, this is not a robust solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866796/making-an-asynchronous-task-in-flask for different ways to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Might be better to solve this with some kind of event based on when the model finishes its job.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Thanks, could you give me some details more?

Comment: Goes way beyond the scope of this site to explain "event-driven architecture", but that's the keyword I would suggest looking up.  May have luck kicking off the job with a websocket or something of that nature as well.

Answer (score 0):

I second with @TheIncorrigible suggestion to solve with some kind of [event driven architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_architecture) what you are doing is Web Worker Architecture. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53254508/python-returning-query-result-from-server-to-client-in-flask)

Your problem reminds me one of the AWS service called `control tower` where launching landing zone of that service takes more than >10min and AWS gracefully handles that. When you try to launch it gives me a banner saying it is progress and would take 1 hour. In console log I noticed they were using Promise(Not exactly sure how they are achieving and [how long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44028891/how-long-a-promise-can-remain-in-pending-state) it can handle).

May be you could try using Promises in react for asynchronous computations. I am not expert but it looks like you can achieve this using that. You may watch [this short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgxTkd43VZ0) for basic understanding.

There is also `signalr` that allows server code to send asynchronous notifications to client-side web applications. You can check if that can be applied in your case [signalr in python dicussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807066/how-signalr-works-internally)